# Non Equi Join in hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

Can someone please help on the below hive query. I know the below wont work as hive doesn't support non equi joins.

```
SELECT a.ymd, a.price_close, b.price_close
FROM   stocks a 
JOIN   stocks b ON a.ymd <= b.ymd
WHERE  a.symbol = 'AAPL' AND b.symbol = 'IBM';
```

Comment: Put the <= condition in where clause, rather using ON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cross join then filter:

```
SELECT a.ymd, a.price_close, b.price_close
FROM   
    (select a.ymd, a.price_close from stocks a where a.symbol = 'AAPL') a
CROSS JOIN (select b.ymd, b.price_close from stocks b where b.symbol = 'IBM') b
WHERE a.ymd <= b.ymd;
```